# Apache Http Components dependency in WAR produces ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpUriRequest in WebSphere

Tags: maven, websphere, war, apache-httpclient-4.x, classnotfoundexception

I have a problem with a maven dependency on a J2ee project (EAR + WAR).
More in detail:

In the WAR project pom I have a JAR application dependency:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>JAR_APP_groupid</groupId>
    <artifactId>JAR_APP_artifactid</artifactId>
    <version>JAR_APP_version</version>
</dependency>
```

the above JAR (JAR_APP) is made by another Maven project which contains the follow dependency:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.httpcomponents</groupId>
    <artifactId>httpclient</artifactId>
    <version>4.5.3</version>
</dependency>
```

The problem is that when I build the WAR I see the JAR_APP dependency and the httpclient (sub)dependency in the lib folder, but when I run the application on the application server (websphere 9.0) I get the following error:

*Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpUriRequest*

I don't know why.
Can you help me ?

Thank you a lot.

Comment: What kind of packaging has the JAR_APP project in Maven?

Comment: May Websphere have its own httpclient in a different version?

Comment: the packaging is JAR

Comment: If it's websphere you need to define httpclient as provided scope...and you have to built against the version which websphere offers.

Comment: I tried to define the org.apache.httpcomponents as provided scope. I also tried to exclude the dependency on the WAR pom... but the problem is still there.

Comment: That you might have the dependency is defined by another dependency...need to check via `mvn dependency:tree` ...

Answer (score 0):

WebSphere already uses Apache Http Components and the classloader picks the one from the system. I think it is possible to change the order the AS loads the dependencies (Parent last).

Comment: I tried to define the org.apache.httpcomponents as provided scope. I also tried to exclude the dependency on the WAR pom... but the problem is still there

Comment: The version is WebSphere might not have the method invoked by JAR_APP_artifactid. Changing the scope you still do not change which version runs on WebSphere.